# Multiple SQL statements causing error, via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a php calendar, as part of a project, and here I am executing some SQL with php:

```
mysql_select_db("waycov_dtm", $con);

$data="'Placeholder Text'";

$sql="INSERT INTO waycov_dtm.calDates (dateID, day, month, year)
VALUES (" . $dateID . ", " . $day . ", " . $month . ", " . $year . ");
INSERT INTO waycov_dtm.calData (dateID, data, memberID)
VALUES (" . $dateID . ", " . $data . ", 1);";

echo $sql;

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
```

When this executes, I get the following (the echoed sql and then the error):

```
INSERT INTO waycov_dtm.calDates (dateID, day, month, year) VALUES (7072012, 7, 07, 2012); INSERT INTO waycov_dtm.calData (dateID, data, memberID) VALUES (7072012, 'Placeholder Text', 1);Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO waycov_dtm.calData (dateID, data, memberID) VALUES (7072012, 'Placeh' at line 3
```

If i take out any one insert statment, the other runs, but both together causes this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO waycov_dtm.calDates (dateID, day, month, year)
VALUES (" . $dateID . ", " . $day . ", " . $month . ", " . $year . ")";
$sql_second = "INSERT INTO waycov_dtm.calData (dateID, data, memberID)
VALUES (" . $dateID . ", " . $data . ", 1);";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con) || !mysql_query($sql_second,$con))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

From the manual:

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not
>   supported)

The use of `mysql_query` is discouraged. Use MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: +1 -- any idea why it would claim the error happened halfway through the word "placeholder"?  Is it due to buffering?

Comment: It seems actually that the error is just before the beginning of the second query (before the `INSERT`)

Comment: Ah yeah I see what you mean.  The fact that it cut off the second query threw me off. `'Placeh' at line 3`

Comment: Thanks! That solved it! Even though a missed dollar sign on sql_second confused me for a second